# How to check method tohavebeencalled or not using jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a function inside functions. I tried to check the inner function called or not using jest. but all test case is failed.

**Sample.ts**

```
export class Sample
{
    update():void
     {
      this.update1()
      this.update2()
     }

     protected update1():void
     {
       console.log('hai');
     }

      protected update2():void
     {
       console.log('hello');
     }
}
```

How to check update() inner function is called or not usinfg jest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jest.spyOn` to do this.

E.g.

`sample.ts`:

```js
export class Sample {
  update(): void {
    this.update1();
    this.update2();
  }

  protected update1(): void {
    console.log('hai');
  }

  protected update2(): void {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
```

`sample.test.ts`:

```js
import { Sample } from './sample';

describe('59466379', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const update1 = jest.spyOn(Sample.prototype, 'update1');
    // @ts-ignore
    const update2 = jest.spyOn(Sample.prototype, 'update2');
    const instance = new Sample();
    instance.update();
    expect(update1).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(update2).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    update1.mockRestore();
    update2.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59466379/sample.test.ts (10.71s)
  59466379
    ✓ should pass (16ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59466379/sample.ts:317
    hai

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59466379/sample.ts:327
    hello

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 sample.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.231s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59466379